# Titanium Android app doesn't show remote images

Tags: javascript, android, database, titanium-mobile

I am developing a Titanium App for iOS and Android. The iOS app is working as expected. I access a local database that holds the name of the image I want to display. When I store the image locally, it displays fine. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var clientlogo = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: 'images/'+rows.fieldByName('clientlogo')+'',
    width:  'auto',
    height: '150dp',
    top:    '1dp'
    });
```

However, I have many images and storing all of them locally will take up far too much space on the device, so I want to store them remotely. I have been unsuccessful in getting it to display with the following snippet:

```
var clientlogo = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image:  'http://mydomain.com/app/uploads/thumb/'+rows.fieldByName('clientlogo')+'',
    width:  'auto',
    height: '150dp',
    top:    '1dp'
    });
```

The image displays properly when viewed through a web browser and I have re-uploaded the image just in case there was some kind of corruption happening to the file. I put a:

```
Ti.API.info('URL: ' + 'http://mydomain.com/app/uploads/thumb/'+rows.fieldByName('clientlogo')+'');
```

in the file to make sure the database was returning a valid URL, and it was. I can get to the remote site on the device via Safari and the image displays properly. I have even tried to put in the exact dimensions of the image to no avail.

Can someone please help me? I am using Titanium SDK 3.1.0, I am testing on an HTC EVO running Android 2.3.5.
NOTE: After further testing I have found that when the path to the image is hardcoded in, the image shows.